# Identifying resistors in parallel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]

So I was studying about resistors at khanacadamy where I got this question.  Apparently the correct answer is A. Shouldn't it be D because R1 is parallel to R2, R3 and  R4 combined? Pls help.
THANKS

Comment: Components are in parallel if they share combining lines. R1 and and R2 clearly share the same wires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of parallel electrical components is that each end of a component is connected to each end of the other component. $R_1$ is definitely in parallel with $R_2$, so $A$ is definitely a correct answer. $R_1$ is also in parallel with the $R_3--R_4$ series connection, but that is not an answer which is offered; but that doesn't mean $A$ is wrong.

Components which are in parallel with each other can *also* be in parallel with additional components. So we could say that $R_2$ is in parallel with the current source.  That does not nullify the fact that it is also in parallel with $R_1$.